# in Flash Builder 4.5, is there any fixable reason why Design view isn't correctly visualizing a simple Label?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, mxml, flex4.5

**Question:**
I tried the very simple code below based on an instructional code snippet, where I create a Label called "headline" with MXML, but use Actionscript to set headline.text = "ABC".

When I use the browser, I see the desired result of the Actionscript - the page displays the text "ABC". But when I use the Design view, it simply shows a blank/white square in that place.

I want to post a screenshot but this is my 1st day on this site, and I don't have the necessary 10 reputation yet.

The relevant code excerpt:

```
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            headline.text="ABC";
        }
    ]]>
     </fx:Script>
     <s:Label id="headline" fontSize="36" x="10" y="10" color="#FFFFFF" />
```

**Answer:**

Because creationCompleteHandler is an event that is set to be completed only upon REAL execution/loading of the application, the code inside that function was running properly in the browser (where the application would be REALLY executed), and not in Design view (where it would be pseudo-executed)

Comment: Problem solved; I've included the solution in the question above. (Any moderator/member: Is that correct method to post answer to one's own question?)

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the text directly in the label:

```
 <s:Label id="headline" fontSize="36" x="10" y="10" color="#FFFFFF" text="ABC" />
```

Or use binding:

```
 <fx:Script>
     <![CDATA[
         [Bindable] public var headlineText:String = "ABC";
     ]]>
 </fx:Script>

 <s:Label text="{headlineText}" id="headline" fontSize="36" x="10" y="10" color="#FFFFFF" />
```

Comment: update @lukevanin: I solved the original problem. Regarding the binding method: I'd like to use it more... But while it worked correctly in browser, on the other hand in Design view of FlashBuilder, it shows "{...}" instead of "ABC". Any suggestions?

Comment: The reason for this is that the code in script tags is not executed at design time. The code needs to be compiled first, which is why it only works at runtime. So while to can see where the variable is going to be placed, the replacement can only happen after the code is compiled and executed. This is a limitation of the architecture behind ActionScript 3 being based on a virtual machine, which prevents it from being interpreted at design time.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, you should mark it as the right answer by clicking on the 'tick' next to it. Or you post your own answer and mark it as correct. IMHO.